# Displaying geographic information from Geoserver in Drupal through openlayers module

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, drupal

I'm trying to display geographic information coming from a local Geoserver instalation (local Tomcat server) in an also local Drupal installation (local Apache server) through openlayers module, but I think I am missing something.

Drupal is working on a local Apache server on port 8888; Geoserver is working on local Tomcat server on port 8080.

Consider the layer "Manhattan (NY) roads" which is installed as example in Geoserver. I can preview it in Geoserver (clicking on "openlayers" button) and the GeoJSON feed is working, if I select it from the dropdown menu, also in Geoserver's Layer Preview page.

**GeoJSON url is:**
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/ows?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=tiger:tiger_roads&maxFeatures=50&outputFormat=application%2Fjson

**and OpenLayers url is:**
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/tiger/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=tiger:tiger_roads&styles=&bbox=-74.02722,40.684221,-73.907005,40.878178&width=476&height=768&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers

I tried using these URL's / portions of it in Drupal through the openlayers modules – creating a source, a layer and a map exposed through a block – but when I enable the block I see no map, only blank space.

I may be entering wrong urls, or selecting wrong source / layer types.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

## EDIT 1

This is the Geoserver log, after trying to preview the map in Drupal:

```
2017-02-03 11:15:22,309 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-02-03 11:15:22,314 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - 
Request: getFeature
service = WFS
version = 1.0.0
baseUrl = http://localhost:8080/geoserver/
query[0]:
typeName[0] = {http://www.census.gov}tiger_roads
maxFeatures = 50
outputFormat = application/json
resultType = results
2017-02-03 11:15:22,315 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON
```

Comment: What do you see in the geoserver logs? What does your client side debug show?

Comment: Client side debug showed "No Access-Control-Allow-Origin" error, but I temporarily solved that by using a Chrome extension (will need to find a real fix later). I've updated my question to include the Geoserver log.

Answer (score 1):

I installed the latest development version of Openlayers3, from Drupal module archive. It solved the problem.